# how to redirect depending on referrer controller ? in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi I want to redirect from a controller function to another depending upon the referrer controller and if possible function . is their a way to do it ???

i mean is their a way to know the controller and or function name of referrer url

i tried

```
   `$rurl= explode(' ', remove_extra_spacess( str_replace(array('http',':',"/"),' ', $this->agent->referrer())));`
```

remove_extra_spacess removes contiguous spaces 
but that is not perfect as index.php may be hidden or may not be and sum other variations .

Comment: add some example. Its very veryy  hard to understand your question

Comment: suppose a dynamic back to previous page button of a controller  function which used in several time so  it have to redirect to specific page depending upon which function it got celled (remember its an controller function not view so i cant use $this->router->fetch_class() )

Comment: Show some example. Edit your question

Answer (score 0):

thanks  Abdulla for your cooperation but it was my communication issue i will improve it definitely any how   have resolve the issue by using an simple trick

```
 $rurl= explode('/',  str_replace(base_url(),'', $this->agent->referrer()));
```

and get the referrer url's controller and function in array

hope it will not give an exception 
so if anyone have any better/ shorter /quicker method to achieve this please share